# Rails:Could not find generator rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, rolify

Edit!

I set up the rolify gem and bundle my app:

I added:

```
gem "rolify" #to add roles like admin and member to the users
```

to the gemfile and then ran

```
bundle install
```

when i try to run

```
rails g rolify Role User
```

I get

```
Could not find generator rolify.
```

Google didn't bring up anything

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added the gem to your Gemfile and run bundle install?

Comment: I would assume, this is a Rails 4.0 App

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had to add the git repository for it to work:

```
gem "rolify",        :git => "git://github.com/EppO/rolify.git"
```

Comment: For future reference the reason this works is that by using the github version you switched to rolify 3.3.0, for which the generator name has changed from `rolify:role` to `rolify`.  For general reference, if you can't find a generator then running `rails g` will list all available generators.

Comment: In the name of OCD: `gem 'rolify', github: 'EppO/rolify'`

Answer (score 7):

I'm on Rails 4.0.0.rc1 and Rolify 3.2.0 and I had to run `rails g rolify:role Role User` instead of `rails g rolify Role User`.

Answer (score 5):

As explained [here](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/137) you could run it using `rails g rolify:role`.